# How to retireve and set data to an MEdit

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my line of code:

```
var temp = $("#MEdit1").get();
```

Then I do:

```
document.writeln(temp);
```

and I get on the screen:

```
[object HTMLInputElement]
```

Why does this happen and what does it mean?

how can I change the code so that if the user enters an integer or a string the variable temp holds that value.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's get() method returns the selector as a jQuery object. This is why you see [object HTMLInputElement]. It is an jQuery object, and an input element. You can test this by running:
`$('#MEdit1').get() instanceof jQuery`, which should return true.

If you want the contents of the input field use:

```
$('#MEdit1").val();
```

you can look at the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfYVz/) to see it in action.